# how to ajax post form as json type to python then get data correct way?

Tags: python, json, ajax

js part

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function(){
              var formData = JSON.stringify($("#contrast_rule_set").serializeArray());
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "./contrast_rule_set",
                  data: formData,
                  success: function(){},
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType : "application/json"
                });
          })
```

python part

```
@app.route('/get_test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_test():
    web_form_data = request.json
    print(web_form_data)
    print(type(web_form_data))
    print(jsonify(web_form_data))
    print(json.dumps(web_form_data))
```

python print console like

```
[{'name': 'logic_1', 'value': '1'}, {'name': 'StudyDescription_1', 'value': ''}, {'name': 'SeriesDescription_1', 'value': 'C\\+'}, {'name': 'ImageComments_1', 'value': ''}, {'name': 'logic_2', 'value': '1'}, {'name': 'StudyDescription_2', 'value': '\\-C'}, {'name': 'SeriesDescription_2', 'value': '\\-C'}, {'name': 'ImageComments_2', 'value': '\\-C'}, {'name': 'logic_3', 'value': '1'}, {'name': 'StudyDescription_3', 'value': ''}, {'name': 'SeriesDescription_3', 'value': '\\+C'}, {'name': 'ImageComments_3', 'value': '\\+C'}]
<class 'list'>
```

how to get list to json data type (or converter )  (html side code adjust or python side code adjust? )
then hope to get data like json type (data is from my another json file )

```
 {
        'Logic': 'AND',
        'StudyDescription': '',
        'SeriesDescription': 'C\+',
        'ImageComments': ''
    },
    {
        'Logic': 'NOT',
        'StudyDescription': '\-C',
        'SeriesDescription': '\-C',
        'ImageComments': '\-C'
    },
    {
        'Logic': 'AND',
        'StudyDescription': '',
        'SeriesDescription': '\+C',
        'ImageComments': '\+C'
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to pretty print the json object?

Comment: no i mean real make list convert to json  or( let ajax form convert right format json format then post to backend side python to get)